# How to reposition a UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have programmatically added a UIRefreshControl as a subview to my UICollectionView.

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyPhotospotsViewController.handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray

    return refreshControl
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

I want to move it down slightly but nothing I have done so far has worked. I tried the following.

```
    refreshControl.frame = CGRect(x: refreshControl.frame.origin.x,
                              y: refreshControl.frame.origin.y - 50,
                              width: refreshControl.frame.size.width,
                              height: refreshControl.frame.size.height)
```

I've also had a look on google but all the answers are in Objective C.

I was thinking of programmatically adding constraints, but that feels incorrect.

Comment: where are you setting this frame in your code, in which function?

Comment: In ViewDidLoad(). I simplified the above ViewDidLoad function

Comment: Try this code : `refreshControl.frame = refreshControl.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0,dy: -50)`

Comment: refreshControl.bounds.origin.y = -50 would work

Comment: Thank you HMHero that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use autolayout constraints for it or update its frame in -viewDidLayoutSubviews.